# JSON parsing rapid api swift corrupted data

Tags: json, swift, api

I’m trying to parse json to find Music Info from tiktok song by Id to play in app, can’t proper make a model to get data. Model that I made with quicktape.io not working. Can someone help me? Here is the link to api https://rapidapi.com/h0p3rwe/api/tiktok-all-in-one

Song id I get by this api: https://ontrend.ai/api/v1/trend/music?type=all , this one is ok.  Problem only with rapidapi

This is my request:

```
func fetch(){
    
    let headers = [ "X-RapidAPI-Key": "0a5efc1659mshadcf7e7123f8554p1e0527jsn74096e7ef6dd",
                    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "tiktok-info.p.rapidapi.com" ]
    
    let musicURL = "https://tiktok-info.p.rapidapi.com/music/6661867221164821250"
    
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: musicURL)! as URL,cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                      timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    
    
    
    
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
        [weak self] data, _ , error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else{
            return
        }
        do{
            
            let songId = try JSONDecoder().decode(MusicSongModel.self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
                print(songId)
            }
        }
        catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }
        
    dataTask.resume()
    
}
```

and this is model:

```
struct MusicSongModelElement: Codable {
    let id, secretID, text: String
    let createTime: Int
    let authorMeta: AuthorMeta
    let musicMeta: MusicMeta
    let covers: Covers
    let webVideoURL, videoURL: String
    let videoURLNoWaterMark, videoAPIURLNoWaterMark: String
    let videoMeta: VideoMeta
    let diggCount, shareCount, playCount, commentCount: Int
    let downloaded: Bool
    let mentions: [JSONAny]
    let hashtags: [Hashtag]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, secretID, text, createTime, authorMeta, musicMeta, covers
        case webVideoURL = "webVideoUrl"
        case videoURL = "videoUrl"
        case videoURLNoWaterMark = "videoUrlNoWaterMark"
        case videoAPIURLNoWaterMark = "videoApiUrlNoWaterMark"
        case videoMeta, diggCount, shareCount, playCount, commentCount, downloaded, mentions, hashtags
    }
}

// MARK: - AuthorMeta
struct AuthorMeta: Codable {
    let id, secUid, name, nickName: String
    let verified: Bool
    let signature: String
    let avatar: String
    let following, fans, heart, video: Int
    let digg: Int
}

// MARK: - Covers
struct Covers: Codable {
    let coversDefault, origin, coversDynamic: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case coversDefault = "default"
        case origin
        case coversDynamic = "dynamic"
    }
}

// MARK: - Hashtag
struct Hashtag: Codable {
    let id, name, title: String
    let cover: String
}

// MARK: - MusicMeta
struct MusicMeta: Codable {
    let musicID, musicName, musicAuthor: String
    let musicOriginal: Bool
    let musicAlbum: String
    let playURL: String
    let coverThumb, coverMedium, coverLarge: String
    let duration: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case musicID = "musicId"
        case musicName, musicAuthor, musicOriginal, musicAlbum
        case playURL = "playUrl"
        case coverThumb, coverMedium, coverLarge, duration
    }
}

// MARK: - VideoMeta
struct VideoMeta: Codable {
    let height, width, duration: Int
}

typealias MusicSongModel = [MusicSongModelElement]

// MARK: - Encode/decode helpers

class JSONNull: Codable, Hashable {

    public static func == (lhs: JSONNull, rhs: JSONNull) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    public var hashValue: Int {
        return 0
    }

    public init() {}

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if !container.decodeNil() {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(JSONNull.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for JSONNull"))
        }
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encodeNil()
    }
}

class JSONCodingKey: CodingKey {
    let key: String

    required init?(intValue: Int) {
        return nil
    }

    required init?(stringValue: String) {
        key = stringValue
    }

    var intValue: Int? {
        return nil
    }

    var stringValue: String {
        return key
    }
}

class JSONAny: Codable {

    let value: Any

    static func decodingError(forCodingPath codingPath: [CodingKey]) -> DecodingError {
        let context = DecodingError.Context(codingPath: codingPath, debugDescription: "Cannot decode JSONAny")
        return DecodingError.typeMismatch(JSONAny.self, context)
    }

    static func encodingError(forValue value: Any, codingPath: [CodingKey]) -> EncodingError {
        let context = EncodingError.Context(codingPath: codingPath, debugDescription: "Cannot encode JSONAny")
        return EncodingError.invalidValue(value, context)
    }

    static func decode(from container: SingleValueDecodingContainer) throws -> Any {
        if let value = try? container.decode(Bool.self) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(Int64.self) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(Double.self) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            return value
        }
        if container.decodeNil() {
            return JSONNull()
        }
        throw decodingError(forCodingPath: container.codingPath)
    }

    static func decode(from container: inout UnkeyedDecodingContainer) throws -> Any {
        if let value = try? container.decode(Bool.self) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(Int64.self) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(Double.self) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decodeNil() {
            if value {
                return JSONNull()
            }
        }
        if var container = try? container.nestedUnkeyedContainer() {
            return try decodeArray(from: &container)
        }
        if var container = try? container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: JSONCodingKey.self) {
            return try decodeDictionary(from: &container)
        }
        throw decodingError(forCodingPath: container.codingPath)
    }

    static func decode(from container: inout KeyedDecodingContainer<JSONCodingKey>, forKey key: JSONCodingKey) throws -> Any {
        if let value = try? container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: key) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(Int64.self, forKey: key) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(Double.self, forKey: key) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: key) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decodeNil(forKey: key) {
            if value {
                return JSONNull()
            }
        }
        if var container = try? container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: key) {
            return try decodeArray(from: &container)
        }
        if var container = try? container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: JSONCodingKey.self, forKey: key) {
            return try decodeDictionary(from: &container)
        }
        throw decodingError(forCodingPath: container.codingPath)
    }

    static func decodeArray(from container: inout UnkeyedDecodingContainer) throws -> [Any] {
        var arr: [Any] = []
        while !container.isAtEnd {
            let value = try decode(from: &container)
            arr.append(value)
        }
        return arr
    }

    static func decodeDictionary(from container: inout KeyedDecodingContainer<JSONCodingKey>) throws -> [String: Any] {
        var dict = [String: Any]()
        for key in container.allKeys {
            let value = try decode(from: &container, forKey: key)
            dict[key.stringValue] = value
        }
        return dict
    }

    static func encode(to container: inout UnkeyedEncodingContainer, array: [Any]) throws {
        for value in array {
            if let value = value as? Bool {
                try container.encode(value)
            } else if let value = value as? Int64 {
                try container.encode(value)
            } else if let value = value as? Double {
                try container.encode(value)
            } else if let value = value as? String {
                try container.encode(value)
            } else if value is JSONNull {
                try container.encodeNil()
            } else if let value = value as? [Any] {
                var container = container.nestedUnkeyedContainer()
                try encode(to: &container, array: value)
            } else if let value = value as? [String: Any] {
                var container = container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: JSONCodingKey.self)
                try encode(to: &container, dictionary: value)
            } else {
                throw encodingError(forValue: value, codingPath: container.codingPath)
            }
        }
    }

    static func encode(to container: inout KeyedEncodingContainer<JSONCodingKey>, dictionary: [String: Any]) throws {
        for (key, value) in dictionary {
            let key = JSONCodingKey(stringValue: key)!
            if let value = value as? Bool {
                try container.encode(value, forKey: key)
            } else if let value = value as? Int64 {
                try container.encode(value, forKey: key)
            } else if let value = value as? Double {
                try container.encode(value, forKey: key)
            } else if let value = value as? String {
                try container.encode(value, forKey: key)
            } else if value is JSONNull {
                try container.encodeNil(forKey: key)
            } else if let value = value as? [Any] {
                var container = container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: key)
                try encode(to: &container, array: value)
            } else if let value = value as? [String: Any] {
                var container = container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: JSONCodingKey.self, forKey: key)
                try encode(to: &container, dictionary: value)
            } else {
                throw encodingError(forValue: value, codingPath: container.codingPath)
            }
        }
    }

    static func encode(to container: inout SingleValueEncodingContainer, value: Any) throws {
        if let value = value as? Bool {
            try container.encode(value)
        } else if let value = value as? Int64 {
            try container.encode(value)
        } else if let value = value as? Double {
            try container.encode(value)
        } else if let value = value as? String {
            try container.encode(value)
        } else if value is JSONNull {
            try container.encodeNil()
        } else {
            throw encodingError(forValue: value, codingPath: container.codingPath)
        }
    }

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        if var arrayContainer = try? decoder.unkeyedContainer() {
            self.value = try JSONAny.decodeArray(from: &arrayContainer)
        } else if var container = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: JSONCodingKey.self) {
            self.value = try JSONAny.decodeDictionary(from: &container)
        } else {
            let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
            self.value = try JSONAny.decode(from: container)
        }
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        if let arr = self.value as? [Any] {
            var container = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
            try JSONAny.encode(to: &container, array: arr)
        } else if let dict = self.value as? [String: Any] {
            var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: JSONCodingKey.self)
            try JSONAny.encode(to: &container, dictionary: dict)
        } else {
            var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
            try JSONAny.encode(to: &container, value: self.value)
        }
    }
```

'''

and the response is:

```
dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around line 1, column 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around line 1, column 0., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=0})))
```

latest time when I try to fetch this code worked for me, but [String : Any] only. Now its too much of request/per day passed

```
func fetchSong() {
    let headers = [
        "X-RapidAPI-Key": "0a5efc1659mshadcf7e7123f8554p1e0527jsn74096e7ef6dd",
        "X-RapidAPI-Host": "tiktok-all-in-one.p.rapidapi.com"
    ]

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://tiktok-all-in-one.p.rapidapi.com/music?id=6661867221164821250")! as URL,
                        cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                      timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
      if (error != nil) {
      } else {
        let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
      }
      if let data = data {
        if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [String : Any] {
          print(json)
        }
      }
    })
    dataTask.resume()
  }
```

Maybe some know good working api for play music by id? And good model data

Comment: Please post a proper example of the JSON you are struggeling with. Also providing the structs and the methods you are using to decode the JSON would be essential to help you solve your problem. Try to read [mre] and [ask] to improve your question.

Comment: do you have a "demo" key/token to test requests to the rapidapi server?

Comment: What's the error you get in `print(error)`? And add a `print("Response stringified: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)")` too.

Comment: Unrelated but avoid `NS(Mutable)Stuff` when `Stuff` is available: `NSMutableULRequest` -> `URLRequest`, `NSURL` -> `URL`, etc.

Comment: can you check (and show us) that your `musicURL` is correct. It seems to be missing at least a `"` but maybe more. I get a response with `"Internal Server Error"`, and off course the `dataCorrupted` decoding error.

Comment: For me this seems like an issue with the service you are using here and not your swift code. If I request this in PostMan I get a 503 error stating "mainenance or capacity issues". The response header indicates no rate limiting in place `X-RateLimit-Requests-Remaining: 1000`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
public func getMusicLink(completion: @escaping (String) -> (), id : String) {
        
        manager.request("https://tiktok-all-in-one.p.rapidapi.com/music?id=\(id)", method: .get, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
            if (response.value != nil) {
                let reponseData = response.value as! [String: Any]
                let musicInfo = reponseData["music_info"] as! [String:Any]
                let playUrls = musicInfo["play_url"] as! [String:Any]
                let playUrl = playUrls["uri"] as! String
                completion(playUrl)
            }
      }
    }
```